# Session Class in PHP stopped working

Tags: php, apache, session, mysqli, php-7

UPDATE:
While migrating to a shared hosting I was trying to figure this issue out. I found the original code for session management here - http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Management-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL

In the end I simply replaced my class with this one, and it started working then, even though, I am pretty sure, I did not change it to begin with. But then I started having a weirder issue. On home server everything worked fine, but on shared hosting every page showed error 503. If I refreshed it a few times I got the same errors as below. Out of curiosity I switched to PHP's native session management and... It worked normally. So my guess is this issue occurs, when the class fails to connect to DB in a timely manner for some reason. After all session class has a few calls to it.

Question is - is there a way to use custom class, while with ability to revert to native one if it fails?

---

When preparing to move my site from local PC to a hosting I encountered some issues with one of the "subsites". It has an authentication system based on common functions used for storing sessions in DB. At some point (and I am unsure at which) it stopped working properly.

So, when I enter incorrect login or password site acts as expected and I get an error message. Since details are checked against database this proves, that connection to database is established. But when I input correct ones - page refreshes as if login succeeded, but it still shows me login page. Nothing is written in the logs.

After a few tries and\or refreshes I do get a 500 server error and following lines in server log:

> [Sun Apr 03 13:29:42.447631 2016] [:error] [pid 12956:tid 1956] [client 192.168.1.1:60985] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed in C:\Users\simbi\OneDrive\Documents\!Personal\projects\WS\apache\htdocs\genfunc\functions.php on line 141, referer: cant_post_too_many_links/edocuments/index.php
>
> [Sun Apr 03 13:29:42.447631 2016] [:error] [pid 12956:tid 1956] [client 192.168.1.1:60985] PHP Warning:  session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active in C:\Users\simbi\OneDrive\Documents\!Personal\projects\WS\apache\htdocs\genfunc\functions.php on line 144, referer: cant_post_too_many_links/edocuments/index.php
>
> [Sun Apr 03 13:29:42.447631 2016] [:error] [pid 12956:tid 1956] [client 192.168.1.1:60985] PHP Warning:  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Users\simbi\OneDrive\Documents\!Personal\projects\WS\apache\htdocs\genfunc\functions.php on line 192, referer: cant_post_too_many_links/edocuments/index.php
>
> [Sun Apr 03 13:29:42.447631 2016] [:error] [pid 12956:tid 1956] [client 192.168.1.1:60985] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null in C:\Users\simbi\OneDrive\Documents\!Personal\projects\WS\apache\htdocs\genfunc\functions.php:195\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\Users\simbi\OneDrive\Documents\!Personal\projects\WS\apache\htdocs\genfunc\globalstart.php(7): session->gc(1)\n#1 C:\Users\simbi\OneDrive\Documents\!Personal\projects\WS\apache\htdocs\edocuments\index.php(2): include_once('C:\\Users\\simbi\\...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in C:\Users\simbi\OneDrive\Documents\!Personal\projects\WS\apache\htdocs\genfunc\functions.php on line 195, referer: cant_post_too_many_links/edocuments/index.php

I thought, that maybe there is something wrong with include in index.php since it showed such a truncated path, but even changing it does not help.

globalstart.php is actually quite small and I do not see an issue here:

```
<?php
#include settings
include_once "../genfunc/config.php";
include_once "../genfunc/functions.php";
$session = new session();
$session->start_session('_s', true);
$session->gc(1);
$loggedin = login_check();
?>
```

It does not like gc(1) apparently. While the line in functions.php is $this->gc_stmt->bind_param('s', $old); in gc($max) function of session class as below:

```
class session {
    function __construct() {
        // set our custom session functions.
        session_set_save_handler(array($this, 'open'), array($this, 'close'), array($this, 'read'), array($this, 'write'), array($this, 'destroy'), array($this, 'gc'));
        // This line prevents unexpected effects when using objects as save handlers.
        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    }
    function start_session($session_name, $secure) {
        // Make sure the session cookie is not accessable via javascript.
        $httponly = true;
        // Hash algorithm to use for the sessionid. (use hash_algos() to get a list of available hashes.)
        $session_hash = 'sha512';
        // Check if hash is available
        if (in_array($session_hash, hash_algos())) {
            // Set the has function.
            ini_set('session.hash_function', $session_hash);
        }
        // How many bits per character of the hash.
        // The possible values are '4' (0-9, a-f), '5' (0-9, a-v), and '6' (0-9, a-z, A-Z, "-", ",").
        ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);
        // Force the session to only use cookies, not URL variables.
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
        // Get session cookie parameters 
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 
        // Set the parameters
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
        // Change the session name 
        session_name($session_name);
        // Now we cat start the session
        session_start();
        // This line regenerates the session and delete the old one. 
        // It also generates a new encryption key in the database. 
        session_regenerate_id(true); 
    }
    function open() {
        global $sesuser, $sespass, $mhost, $mdbname, $mport, $msocket;
        $mysqli = new mysqli($mhost, $sesuser, $sespass, $mdbname, $mport, $msocket);
        $this->db = $mysqli;
        return true;
    }
    function close() {
        $this->db->close();
        return true;
    }
    function read($id) {
        if(!isset($this->read_stmt)) {
            $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM `ed__sessions` WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
        }
        $this->read_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->read_stmt->execute();
        $this->read_stmt->store_result();
        $this->read_stmt->bind_result($data);
        $this->read_stmt->fetch();
        $key = $this->getkey($id);
        $data = $this->decrypt($data, $key);
        return $data;
    }
    function write($id, $data) {
        // Get unique key
        $key = $this->getkey($id);
        // Encrypt the data
        $data = $this->encrypt($data, $key);
        $time = time();
        if(!isset($this->w_stmt)) {
            $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO `ed__sessions` (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        }
        $this->w_stmt->bind_param('siss', $id, $time, $data, $key);
        $this->w_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    function destroy($id) {
        if(!isset($this->delete_stmt)) {
            $this->delete_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `ed__sessions` WHERE id = ?");
        }
        $this->delete_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->delete_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    function gc($max) {
        if(!isset($this->gc_stmt)) {
            $this->gc_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `ed__sessions` WHERE set_time < ?");
        }
        $old = time() - $max;
        $this->gc_stmt->bind_param('s', $old);
        $this->gc_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    private function getkey($id) {
        if(!isset($this->key_stmt)) {
            $this->key_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT session_key FROM `ed__sessions` WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
        }
        $this->key_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->key_stmt->execute();
        $this->key_stmt->store_result();
        if($this->key_stmt->num_rows == 1) { 
            $this->key_stmt->bind_result($key);
            $this->key_stmt->fetch();
            return $key;
        } else {
            $random_key = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
            return $random_key;
        }
    }
    private function encrypt($data, $key) {
        $salt = 'u@cewPpn7e9R9pE2HUe-ebH7=EcC!*7Tw!s4espu@hsWDR3DtDuHrGu6hEAGrrHe';
        $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
        return $encrypted;
    }
    private function decrypt($data, $key) {
        $salt = 'u@cewPpn7e9R9pE2HUe-ebH7=EcC!*7Tw!s4espu@hsWDR3DtDuHrGu6hEAGrrHe';
        $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

Honestly, I fail to see what is wrong here, since this is pretty general code, I copied from some other site several years ago and it worked before. But I noticed in the database, that there are 2 sessions created during login for some reason. Maybe that the reason it fails, but I do not understand why the second one gets created.

Can someone advise? If needed I can add some other portions of the code relevant to this.

Comment: _“Failed to decode session object”_ – that suggests that the data you are reading from the database is not the same as was written into it in the first place. Go make debug outputs to verify.

Comment: it fails to decode, because it fails to get the data. this is the conclusion I reached.